# ¿Cómo cambiar un número en Hover con CSS?

Tags: html, css

Resulta que estoy intentando hacer que un precio cambie conforme al color que se elija, comencé usando un checkbox y CSS para la visualización del precio pero solo me arroja un solo cambio de precio en lugar de usar precios diferentes, independientemente uno del otro

```css
#original {
  position: relative;
}
#checkbox {
  display: none;
}


#checkbox:hover + #original:after {
  content: "$30";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
}
#color1:checked + #original:after {
  content: "$29.95";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
}

#color2:hover + #original:after {
  content: "$75";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
<label id="original" >$24.5</label>
<br><br><br>
<label id="color1" for="checkbox">rosa</label>
<br><br><br>
<label id="color2" for="checkbox">morado</label>
</html>
```

Comment: No termina de quedar claro qué es lo que quieres realizar. ¿Quieres que el precio sea diferente cuando se pase por encima de "rosa" y "morado"? ¿qué es el cuarto precio y cuándo debería ocurrir?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Sí, así es, tendría que dar precios distintos conforme a los distintos colores, el precio original es 24.5, en rosa debería cambiar a 29.95 y en morado a 75

Comment: ¿Puedes cambiar el orden del html?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Sí, no necesariamente tiene que ser de ese modo, es sólo que así se me ocurrió

Answer (score 3):

Por qué no te funciona el código que tienes: el elemento `#contenedor` aparece en el código antes que los elementos `#color1` y `#color2`, entonces los dos selectores:

```
#color1:checked + #original:after { ... }
#color2:hover + #original:after { ... }
```

no se aplicarán porque lo que hacen es seleccionar el id `#original` que aparezca justo después de `#color1` y `#color2`, que no es el caso. Y tampoco sería el caso si mueves `#original` a después de esos dos elementos, porque sólo habría un `#original` y no podría estar de forma consecutiva detrás de `#color1` y `#color2` (sólo se aplicaría uno de los dos).

---

Una posible alternativa: mueve `#original` a después de `#color1` y `#color2`, y utiliza el [combinador de hermano general (`~`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_hermanos_generales) para que se pueda seleccionar `#original` incluso cuando no aparezca de forma adyacente a ninguno de los dos elementos:

```
#color1:checked ~ #original:after { ... }
#color2:hover ~ #original:after { ... }
```

Con ese cambio el código se vería así:

```css
#original {
  position: relative;
}
#checkbox {
  display: none;
}


#checkbox:hover + #original:after {
  content: "$30";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
}
#color1:hover ~ #original:after {
  content: "$29.95";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
}

#color2:hover ~ #original:after {
  content: "$75";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<html>


<label id="color1" for="checkbox">rosa</label>
<br><br><br>
<label id="color2" for="checkbox">morado</label>
<br><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
<label id="original" >$24.5</label>

</html>
```

---

Pero ahora ya no se ve exactamente como quieres porque `#original` aparece después. Puedes cambiar aún un poquito más tu código para que, aunque aparezca después en el código, se muestre por delante de los otros dos elementos. Por ejemplo, usando `flexBox` y la propiedad `order`:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#original {
  position: relative;
  order: 1;
}

#checkbox {
  display: none;
}

label {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  order:2;
}

#checkbox:hover+#original:after {
  content: "$30";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
}

#color1:hover~#original:after {
  content: "$29.95";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
}

#color2:hover~#original:after {
  content: "$75";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
<label id="color1" for="checkbox">rosa</label>
<label id="color2" for="checkbox">morado</label>
<label id="original">$24.5</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

a lo que entiendo lo que estás intentando hacer hover a un objeto y afectar a otro
esto te puede servir.

Si el original está directamente en el contenedor:

```
#container:hover > #original {  }
```

Si el original es la siguiente (después de los contenedores de la etiqueta de cierre) el contenedor:

```
#container:hover + #original {  }
```

si el original está después de los siguientes

```
#container:hover ~ #original {  }
```

Si el original está en algún lugar en el interior del contenedor:

```
#container:hover #original {  }
```

**Adyacente "+"**: Selecciona al hermano adyacente, es decir, al que viene justo después en el DOM.

**General "~"**: Selecciona a todos los hermanos que están después del elemento en el DOM.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Te falta uno que seguramente es el que será más útil para el usuario en este caso: `~`.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Cierto no lo había visto gracias por mencionarlo, ya lo edito.